# Why can't python third-level nested classes inherit from each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-classes

This code is valid in python:

```
class Inner:
    class InnerInner:
        attr = 1

class Inner2(Inner):
    class InnerInner2(Inner.InnerInner):
        attr = 2
```

Why is the following not possible in python?

```py
class Outer:
    class Inner:
        class InnerInner:
            attr = 1

    class Inner2(Inner):
        class InnerInner2(Inner.InnerInner):
            attr = 2
```

It gives me following error:

> class InnerInner2(Inner.InnerInner):
>   NameError: name 'Inner' is not defined

I would expect that `Inner` would be completely defined before definition of `Inner2` starts.

Comment: Should it not be `class InnerInner2(Outer.Inner.InnerInner):`? The same way you need to specify the class name when calling a static method from within the class. But also - this seems like a complex design, is it really necessary to be defining classes inside other classes? Isn't composition preferable?

Comment: It would be `Outer.Inner.InnerInner`, but `Outer` isn't defined yet.

Comment: I would have thought `Outer` is defined. If you have a static method in a class, you can call that method from within the same class using `ClassName.static_method`. I don't see why this is different :(

Comment: Note that there's very little practical use of nested classes, much less double nested classes, much less double nested class inheritance, to begin with. Most of the time if you're using nested classes you're already doing it wrong.

Comment: @Dan: If you try to *actually call* the static method before the class definition finishes, `ClassName` will be undefined.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica not sure I understand you. If I have a class with static method a and another method b, I can called ClassName.a inside of b. Isn't that stil within the class definition?

Comment: @Dan: If you try to actually call the staticmethod, rather than just writing another method that *would* call the staticmethod when run, you'll see a failure.

Comment: @Dan: https://ideone.com/3UO9sv

Comment: Ok so you're saying that this is different https://ideone.com/rFT5jh because it only gets defined during the class definition but only gets called later. Whereas in your snippet you are trying to actually call the method inside the class def?

Comment: Makes sense to me :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same reason this fails:

```
class Foo:
    a = 1
    def bar(self):
        return a
Foo().bar()
```

Just like code inside `bar` can't see anything inside `Foo`'s scope, code inside `Inner2` can't see anything from `Outer`'s scope.

`Inner` *is* completely defined by the point you try to use it, but it's in a scope you can't access.

Comment: But in this case you can make it `return Foo.a` and it works. For some (different) reason you can't inherit from `Outer.Inner.InnerInner` in the OP case.

Comment: @Dan: `Inner` is defined, but `Outer` isn't.

Comment: But I'm saying I don't think the reasons are the same here. Because `Foo` is defined enough inside of `bar` to be able to call `Foo.a`. The same doesn't seem to hold with `Outer` in the OP. So isn't there something different here?